# Efficiency: member variable vs local variable in a timer

Tags: c#, performance, variables, timer

I could not find similar questions here, so I am posting new one. 
In c# program with timer, what is more efficient:

1. Declaring member variable, then using with each timer tick, it to calculate and change its value, or
2. Declaring local variable inside a timer_tick routine, and declaring it each time, recalculating, using it, and then with next tick - doing it all over again ?

Example code:

```
ClassOne
{
    float mVar1 = 0;

    Timer_Tick
    {
        mVar1 += CurrentSpeed;
        SpeedOfSomething = mVar1;
    }
}
```

OR:

```
ClassOne
{
    Timer_Tick
    {
        float Var1 = 0;
        Var1 += CurrentSpeed;
        SpeedOfSomething = Var1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Before talking about what is more efficient, we should be comparing two methods that have the same, correct behavior. These psuedo-code descriptions do different things after the first tick, so talking about which is more efficient is moot. Choose the one that is correct first.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Second (and this follows on eric lippert's article that @itsme86 posted), define efficiency. Let's say you modify this example to have two identical behaviors but one uses more CPU and less memory and the other uses more memory and less CPU. This is a classic space-time tradeoff. Which is more efficient derives from what is more important, memory or CPU. Which resource are you constrained by?

Comment: In addition to what mike z said, more efficient is compelety useless if the fastest solution doesn´t gets the job done. So concentrate first on what you **need to do** and optimize if you **have to optimize**. Having said this the best way to compare both approaches is by simply **measuring them**, e.g. using `StopWatch`, or some more sophisticated a profiler such as DotTrace.

Comment: A local variable is always more efficient.  The jitter optimizer cannot afford the kind of deep code analysis that ensures that another method is not accessing a member variable as well.  And worse, another thread.  So it cannot eliminate the store.  A local variable often completely disappears, one basic reason that Reflection gives no access at all to locals.  The second snippet would of course be written as SpeedOfSomething = CurrentSpeed, but that doesn't actually make a difference.  The optimizer can figure that out by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the second one:

```
 Timer_Tick
    {
        float Var1 = 0;
        Var1 += CurrentSpeed;
        SpeedOfSomething = Var1;
    }
```

Every time that Timer_Tick is fired, `float Var1 = 0;` will be executed and actually `Var1` value will always be `0`. So its not a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically the optimizer can have full knowledge of the access pattern for a locally scoped variable, whereas a public or class level variable might have multi-threaded access. Although only an examination of the IL code will give you a definitive answer, the based purpose of scoping variables is to make them visble to as little other code as possible. Happily in this case the tightest scoping is likely to be the most efficient, assuming the optimized can make use of the full lifecycle knowledge of your variable to completely eliminate you intermediate add operations, and in fact may completely eliminate the variable from the pre-compiled code.